# How to make 1 IBOutlet works for different devices?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard, xib

Say I got a general iPhone size and iPad size to work out.

The iPad has a `UIButton` that links to `UIViewController` as a `IBOutlet`. 
Whereas iPhone doesn't need this `UIButton` but since iPhone and iPad all in 1 `Storyboard` and any other `IBOutlet` are identical. What is the most proper way to deal with this?

What I am thinking is to make the `@IBOutlet weak var button:UIButton?` optional and only the iPad's button links to it. But every action I do in the code requires `button?.xxxxx`

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should be able to use Trait Variations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change the layout depending on device. Apple now starts using size classes to describe their devices. Currently, iPads all have a horizontal size class of "Regular" and a vertical size class of "Regular" when in full screen (it's different when you do multitasking on an iPad).

Select your button and go to the properties inspector. Scroll down and you'll find this "Installed" property:

[image]

Click on the "+" sign and this should appear:

[image]

Select "Regular" for both "width" and "height". Now you should see two "Installed" properties - one for wRhR and one for everything else. Just uncheck the one for everything else to only have the button on iPads.

[image]

Now you need to be careful in code. As your button can be `nil` on a phone. Remember to do nil checks!

Comment: so `@IBOutlet weak var button:UIButton?` instead of `@IBOutlet weak var button:UIButton!` is required?

Comment: @TonyLin It's not _required_ because `!` is an optional as well. I recommend `?` because it forces you to make a choice about what to do with it - force unwrap it or not.

Comment: my question is in my example there's 1 button exists in the iPhone size but not in iPad size. This button is linked to my `ViewController` file as an IBOutlet. Then if it's a `!`. That means if I setup my `ViewController` like `button.backgroundColor = xxx` it would crash, right? but if I made it as a `?` then I can do `button?.xxx` instead. Is this the only way to solve this problem? @Sweeper

Comment: @TonyLin If you do `button.backgroundColor = xxx` it would indeed crash. But you can still do `button?.xxx` with a `UIButton!`. But `UIButton?` will _force_ you to add a `?`.

Comment: I see, so is this the only solution to this particular problem? @Sweeper

Comment: @TonyLin No matter what you do, you are going to have an optional in your VC. You could also create the button in code, depending on size classes. Alternatively, you can show different VC's depending on size classes. That way you don't need an optional, but will probably lead to a lot of duplicate code.